# file_exists returning false for unknown reason

Tags: file-permissions

I have the following file:

```
/home/user/public_html/web-site.org/download/audio/1999/01-03 Good News.mp3
```

The problem is that the error is thrown and the file is exited when it exists.  I'm checking for file_exists because I'm doing a `copy()` later and it's failing cause the file doesn't existing.  I'm hosted on hostGator and my permissions on these mp3s are `755`.

```
if (!file_exists('/home/user/public_html/web-site.org/download/audio/'.$sermon['year'].'/'.$sermon['file'])) {
    echo "Oops, file doesn't exist: <b>/home/user/public_html/web-site.org/download/audio/".$sermon['year']."/".$sermon['file']."</b>";
    exit;
}
```

Could it be the space in the filename?  I have about 1,100 audio files to process, so changing the filename manually would be a nightmare...

**update**

`urlencode()` and `trim()` on the filename has no effect

`str_replace(' ', '-', $sermon['file'])` on the filename doesn't work (after changing spaces to dashes in the filename itself)

I checked the permissions on the folder the file is in, it WAS `700` and I changed it to `755` and it had no effect.

**update**

I read in another thread that having a `.` in the path anywhere could cause a problem... so I changed `.org` to `_org` and the problem persisted, so I've reverted those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow.... fail on my part.... epic fail.... my user path was wrong

Comment: Edit you're original question, don't post this as an answer.

Comment: .... it is the answer.  And that's the only way to really "close out" the question

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the spaces in the filename.

```
/home/user/public_html/web-site.org/download/audio/1999/01-03\ Good\ News.mp3
```